# Does the sign of the numerator matter in the "arctan-angle-line" formula?

Tags: coordinate-systems, angle, slope

So the simplified formula for finding the acute angle between two intersecting lines is:
tan-¹ (m1-m2/1+m1m2)
But what if m2 is larger than m1 and we get a negative numerator? Does the formula still hold?

Comment: Parentheses, please.  You have written the argument as $m1-\frac {m2}{1}+m1m2$, which is not what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right formula is
$$\alpha=\arctan\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$$

Let $l_1$ and $l_2$ be two straight lines and $\alpha$ be a measure of the angle between $l_1$ and $l_2$.

Thus, if $l_1||l_2$ then $\alpha=0^{\circ}$;

if $l_1\perp l_2$ then $\alpha=90^{\circ}$;

otherwise, $\alpha$ it's a measure of the small angle between four angles,

which which we get by these lines.

Comment: OP was asking about the sign of the calculation.  If you take off the absolute value bars, it indicates which direction  you are measuring, clockwise or counterclockwise

Comment: @Ross Millikan See please better my answer. I said that the formula, which he try to use is total wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Ross Millikan. It's just that everywhere I look, I see the formula without absolute value bars, so that got me thinking. So without them we get the same answer, just with respect to the direction we measure the angle from?

Comment: @user485842:  The arctan function is odd, so if you change the sign of the argument, you change the sign of the result.  That corresponds to measuring in the other sense.